# Эмулятор Android Studio 2.2.3 на windows

Tags: android, android-studio

Я начал учиться создавать приложения под Android. Создаю первую программу. OC у меня windows 10. Почему-то справа в preview не показывается, как должно выглядеть приложение и в android sdk пишет, что эмулятор не совместим с windows. Так вот, что мне делать? Кто пишет на windows подскажите ребят пожалуйста

Comment: Используйте Genymotion в качестве эмулятора

Comment: а как это все будет работать? он будет как расширение или как?

Comment: Это отдельная программа. Из неё запускаете эмулятор нужный далее студия видит его как девайс для запуска

Comment: у вас наверное процессор AMD? тогда используйте ARM-образы системы(а не Intel) при создании эмулятора, но работать это будет довольно медленно. Приемлемым решением будет физическое устройство, подключеное по USB в режиме разработчика (так же потребуется установить подходящий для этого устройства драйвер ADB) или стороний эмулятор вроде Genimotion.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). Для обучения и некоммерческих проектов бесплатен. Требует регистрации на сайте.

После установки и запуска любой эмулятор (как родной, так и Genymotion) должен появиться в списке устройств, на которых можно запустить ваше приложение.